# detected unhandled Python exception

Tags: python, linux, web-services, nginx, webserver

```
abrt: detected unhandled Python exception in '/usr/local/cpanel/hooks/addondomain/addaddondomain'
```

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import sys
import os
import yaml
from xml.dom import minidom
sys.path.append('/scripts')
import createvhosts
doc = minidom.parse(sys.stdin)

resulttaglist = doc.getElementsByTagName('result')
resultlist =[]

if resulttaglist[1].childNodes[0].toxml() == 0:
        sys.exit
else:
        subdomaintaglist = doc.getElementsByTagName('subdomain')
        subdomain = subdomaintaglist[0].childNodes[0].toxml()
        maindomaintaglist = doc.getElementsByTagName('DOMAIN')
        maindomain = maindomaintaglist[0].childNodes[0].toxml()
        domain =  subdomain + '.' + maindomain
        usertaglist = doc.getElementsByTagName('USER')
        user = usertaglist[0].childNodes[0].toxml()
        docroot, yip, alias = createvhosts.getvars(domain)
        serverip = createvhosts.getmainip()
                if yip == serverip:
                        createvhosts.writeconfshared(user, domain, docroot, yip, alias)
                else:
                        createvhosts.writeconfded(user, domain, docroot, yip, alias)
        proc = subprocess.Popen("/etc/init.d/nginx restart > /dev/null 2>&1", shell=True)
```

I was just wondering could this be a python version issue?

```
ls /usr/bin | grep python*
abrt-action-analyze-python*
python*
python2@
python2.6*
python2.6-config*
python-config@
```

I assume I am using python 2.6?

**EDIT**
This also used to never happen. The other thing I noticed was the process won't die and will remain seen when you do `ps -ef`

Comment: `sys.exit` won't do anything without parentheses.  don't use `shell=True` if you can avoid it, which you easily can here.  re the actual question, this would seem to be a cpanel problem; is there a more detailed log somewhere?  can you run this script manually and see what happens?

Comment: If I add addon domains from the panel the script will run. How should I debug/log everything?